# Text progress bar in Matlab

Tags: matlab, progress-bar

I've got a Matlab function that takes some time to run, and I'd like to show the user that progress is being made. Just `disp`ing the progress every 5% or so would clutter the screen too much, as the previous text would not be erased.

How can this problem be solved? There's other important information in the command window, so clearing it is out of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `waitbar` function for that. See [MATLAB Documentation on waitbar](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/waitbar.html).

Comment: I was looking for a text version, but that was only because I didn't know how useful `waitbar` was. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Showing the progess in the Command Window is also possible (and maybe easier).
I found a very simple, fast to implement solution on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/command-window-text-manipulation/.

```
reverseStr = '';
for idx = 1 : someLargeNumber

   % Do some computation here...

   % Display the progress
   percentDone = 100 * idx / someLargeNumber;
   msg = sprintf('Percent done: %3.1f', percentDone); %Don't forget this semicolon
   fprintf([reverseStr, msg]);
   reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
end
```

If you embedd this code the command line is showing (for example): "Percent done: 27.8" without entering a newline every iteration!

Comment: Note: this doesn't work on Octave, where standard output is buffered.

Answer (score 2):

check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3607-progressbar and
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26773-progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is written by @Ergodicity is correct, just for Octave if you set the standard output to be buffered (which is default btw), you had to enable it by page_output_immediately(1); see this page for more [octave doc: Terminal output](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Paging-Screen-Output.html#XREFpage_005foutput_005fimmediately)

a very brief modifications on the proposed code:

```
reverseStr = '';
fprintf('Percent done: ');
for idx = 1 : someLargeNumber
   % Do some computation here...
   % Display the progress
   percentDone = 100 * idx / someLargeNumber;
   msg = sprintf('%3.1f', percentDone); %Don't forget this semicolon
   fprintf([reverseStr, msg]);
   reverseStr = repmat(sprintf('\b'), 1, length(msg));
end
```